# Интерпретатор Node в линукс

Tags: node.js, phpstorm, linux-mint

Друзья, помогите пожалуйста настроить Node и npm в линуксе. В нем я не силен. Провисел уже дня три с решением этой проблемы. файл node находится в /usr/bin/node но PhpStorm его просто не видит. Менял права доступа к папкам, попытался к самому node файлу поменять права, но проблему это не решает.

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Может попробовать поставить пакет node для дистрибутива, которым Вы пользуетесь? Конечно иногда в дистрибутивах бывает старьё, как в дебияне например. Но тогда можно нагуглить интсрукцию как поставить что-то новенькое.

Comment: А в консоли работает?

Comment: Не пробовали ещё `sudo apt install nodejs` и `sudo apt install npm`? У меня в дебияне именно так и установлено. Поскольку линух-минт основан на дебияне и убунту, то есть основания надеяться, что и там сработает.

Comment: а как именно вы ставили PhpStorm? Не с помощью flatpak часом? Из соображений безопасности приложения, установленные Flatpak не имеют доступа к файлам хоста. Это может вызвать кучу проблем - IDE просто не видит установленные в системе файлы